# Word for "doing something pridefully"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb form of "pride"? For example, is there a concise way to say something like

> She read her own paper with great pride

I'm looking for a more concise verb that still indicates that self-masturbatory feeling of being proud of one's own work. Something that could fit the sentence:

> She [prided] over her paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Preen" might work here.

One can preen over a paper.

preen verb (2)
preened; preening; preens
Definition of preen (Entry 3 of 3)
transitive verb

1 of a bird : to groom with the bill especially by rearranging the barbs and barbules of the feathers and by distributing oil from the uropygial gland
2 : to dress or smooth (oneself) up : PRIMP
3 : to pride or congratulate (oneself) on an achievement

Comment: I like this one a lot; merriam-webster's definition is "to behave or speak with obvious pride or self-satisfaction", which is perfect

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I found

> ### [Belaud](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belaud)
>
> to praise usually to excess

Which could work. It has the negative connotation I was hoping for

Comment: I like that.   Belauded as a past tense, I'm guessing.